# phpRedis - How to push/get key from another namespace?

Tags: php, redis, phpredis

I have one database (`db0`) and 2 namespaces: `space1`, `space2`.
For my code I'm using phpRedis (https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis) library.
Example "string": `space1_:main_site_products:77-005_expire`.
How can I get this key from `space2`? Or how can I put key to another space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you must create a new connection to server with option (2nd parameter) `prefix` setted to `space1_`, then get your key by `$redisSpace1->get('main_site_products:77-005_expire');`

Comment: So I'm create connection via `$redisSpace1 = new \Predis\Client(['port' => 12769, 'password' => 'redisServer']);` but where enter this `2nd parameter`?

Comment: As we both wrote - 2nd parameter in connection. So your connection will be `$redisSpace1 = new \Predis\Client(['port' => 12769, 'password' => 'redisServer'], ['prefix' => 'space1_']);`. First array had connection parameters like host, password, etc. and second has connection OPTIONS like prefix. More in docs: https://github.com/nrk/predis/wiki/Home

Comment: Ohh... My mistake, I didn't see it. Thanks! That's solving my problem :)